# Can someone explain to me reduce sum in tensorFlow.js

Tags: tensorflow.js

When I use the reduce sum of tensorFlow.js as : https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#sum , I was thinking that it would simply add all the element of an array to get a sum.  But apparently it's something more complicated than that.

```
const x = tf.tensor([12, 12, 24]).sum().print();

// result :  60
```

I would be expecting 48

Answer (score 0):

[sum](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#sum) gives the sum of the tensor. By default all dimensions are reduced, but you can pass as parameter to the `sum`, the dimension(s) to reduce. 
The code of the question will output the sum of all the elements of the tensor (exactly what is expected)

```js
const x = tf.tensor([12, 12, 24]).sum();

x.print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a problem with Ubuntu and tfjs 0.12.0

Comment: I don't know the details of the problem, but the result was corrupt when using SUM